# Плавное изменение цвета в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно что бы спрайт плавное изменял свой цвет в красный оттенок  ,а потом обратно в свой дефолтный (хочу сделать мигание).
Возможно ли такое реализовать скриптом или нужно через анимацию?

Comment: Возможно, смотрите в сторону [Color.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html)

Comment: А ещё шейдером очень просто, 1 строчка =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение на основе шейдера, ИМХО поинтереснее

Создаем стандартный `image effect shader` и добавляем такую строчку в секции, отвечающую за фрагментный шейдер:

```
// вычитаем синус от времени из расстояния до центра
col.gb = sqrt(dot(i.uv-0.5, i.uv-0.5))-_SinTime.a;
```

и добавляем поддержку розрачности

```
Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
```

Шейдер целиком

```html
Shader "NewImageEffectShader"
{
 Properties
 {
  _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
 }
 SubShader
 {
    /// поддержка прозрачности
   Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    ///
  Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

  Pass{
   CGPROGRAM
   #pragma vertex vert
   #pragma fragment frag
   
   #include "UnityCG.cginc"

   struct appdata
   {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
   };

   struct v2f
   {
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
   };

   v2f vert (appdata v)
   {
    v2f o;
    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
    o.uv = v.uv;
    return o;
   }
   
   sampler2D _MainTex;

   fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
   {
    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
        
        /// убавляем значение цвета для зеленого и синего канала (оставляя красный)
        /// по простенькой формуле
        
        col.gb = sqrt(dot(i.uv-0.5, i.uv-0.5)) - _SinTime.a;
    
        return col;
   }
   ENDCG
  }
 }
}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: а если еще немножко подумать

```
col.gb -= abs(sqrt(sqrt(dot(i.uv-0.5, i.uv-0.5)))-_SinTime.a);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PPS: линии на картинках потому что видео снято с окна инспектора

Answer (score 0):

Вариант предложенный в комментарии гражданином `vmchar`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Blink : MonoBehaviour {

    Image image;

    void Start () {
        image = GetComponent<Image> (); 
    }

    void Update () {
        image.color = Color.Lerp (Color.red, Color.white, Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Sin(Time.time)));
    }
}
```